# boto - slow set_content_from_file when get_bucket validate is False

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I'm trying to upload ~3k files (1 kilobyte each) to boto using [GreenPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720735/fastest-way-to-download-3-million-objects-from-a-s3-bucket).

**My question:**

Why does `get_bucket()` call takes so long per call, what causes the trade-off with `set_content()` time? and how can I get around it. Thanks!

**More details:**

- `get_bucket(validate=True)` takes 30 seconds in average, and the following `set_content_from_file_name` takes under 1 sec.
- I tried changing to `validate=False`, this successfully reduced `get_bucket()` time to under 1 sec, but then the time for `set_content_from_file_name` jumped up to ~30 seconds. I couldn't find the reason for this trade-off in the [boto docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html).

**Code:**

```
def upload(bucket_str, key_str, file_path):

    # new s3 connection
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()

    # get bucket
    bucket_time = time.time()
    b = s3.get_bucket (bucket_name, validate=True)
    logging.info('get_bucket Took %f seconds'%(time.time()-bucket_time))

    # get key
    key_time = time.time()
    key = mapping_bucket.new_key(key_str)
    logging.info('new_key Took %f seconds'%(time.time()-key_time))

    for i in range(S3_TRIES):
        try:
            up_time = time.time()
            key.set_contents_from_filename (file_path,
            headers={
                "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            policy='public-read')
            logging.info('set_content Took %f seconds'%(time.time()-up_time))
            key.set_acl('public-read')
            return True

        except Exception as e:
            logging.info('try_set_content exception iteration - %d, %s'%(i, str(e)))
            _e = e

    raise _e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the doc for [`get_bucket`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.connection.S3Connection.get_bucket)

> If `validate=False` is passed, no request is made to the service (no
>   charge/communication delay). This is only safe to do if you are sure
>   the bucket exists.
>
> If the default `validate=True` is passed, a request is made to the
>   service to ensure the bucket exists. Prior to Boto v2.25.0, this
>   fetched a list of keys (but with a max limit set to 0, always
>   returning an empty list) in the bucket (& included better error
>   messages), at an increased expense. As of Boto v2.25.0, this now
>   performs a HEAD request (less expensive but worse error messages).

After this when you call `set_contents_from_filename` it needs to open the s3 key for reading so at this time it will make the request to s3.

As back to your question about uploading large number of files, and since you tag your questions with boto3, I would suggest you move to boto3 and look at the [Transfer Manager](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#using-the-transfer-manager)